# Find a individual word location in a list that isn't its own value

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

I am trying to find a specific word in a list. As simple as it sounds, me and the people I've talked to can't think of an answer. Below is an example of my issue.

```
list = ['this is ', 'a simple ', 'list of things.']
```

I want to find the word `"simple"` in the list, and note its location. (Aka `list[1]` in this example.)

I've tried a few methods, for example:

```
try:
  print(list.index("simple"))
except (ValueError) as e:
    print(e)
```

Which will always return as `'simple'` is not in list.

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Related: [Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](//stackoverflow.com/q/4843158)

Comment: Never fails, when you post on stack overflow 99/100 times you get hit with a [duplicate] or a related xD

Comment: @ChadHendrixs 1/100 is not never though. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [list.index](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.index) function searches for occurence of exact 'simple' string in the list, i.e. it does not do any substring searches. To complete your task you can use `in` operator and do comparison for every string in a list:

```
my_list = ['this is ', 'a simple ', 'list of things.']


def find_string(l, word):
    for i, s in enumerate(l):
        if word in s:
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError('"{}" is not in list'.format(word))


try:
    print(find_string(my_list, "simple"))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through list and check if the word is in the list items and get its index by making a variable. Here is a sample code:

```
list = ['this is ', 'a simple ', 'list of things.']
word = "simple"

for item in list:
    if word in item:
        print(list.index(item))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each element in the list, and the determine if your word is in the list. You can define a function to handle this:

```
def word_check(my_list, word):
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
        if word in my_list[i]:
            return i
    return False


list = ['this is ', 'a simple ', 'list of things.']

word_check(list, 'simple')
```

The function will return the index of the word if found, else it will return false.